# How can I get start with the development with Web Center content web service?

Tags: webcenter, webcenter-sites

Forgive me I am a newbie for Web Center Content. Currently I want to implement a tools which can list, view, create, delete document of Web Center Content.

But I totally have no idea to how to get start with this work.

Say I have the background of Asp.net and C# development experience.

Is there any web service of WCC could be referened to implement the functions I mentioned.

If there is , What is the WSDL url exactly?

Or , If there does't exist any web service api to be comsumed, Is there any .Net SDK to get start?

And If there is some sample code to demonstrate. It will be nice!

Thanks in advance,

Joe

Comment: Execuse me , If it is the wrong place to get help, Please close it, I am sorry for that . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your starting point would be the Oracle WebCenter Content documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/nav/webcontent.htm

It is a Java-based product and offers several means of integration:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e26694/part7_integrate_apps.htm#CIHJHEHA

RIDC is used often to integrate with Java-based applications, but web services are available as well, see the above link.

Comment: Hi Jaap, Thanks your reply +1, Is there any sample code to demo?

Comment: I don't have any sample code for you, but perhaps this blog post from Oracle's A-Team may be useful: http://www.ateam-oracle.com/moving-to-oracle-webcenter-content-11g-web-services/

Answer (score 1):

The GenericSoapService is the web services interface for WebCenter Content 11g.

Official docs on WCC 11g web services is here. 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e10807/c19_web_services.htm#CSSDK816

There is more detail at this link, with some sample Java code.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/soa/mcdonald-webcenter-content-services-1930993.html

A fair amount of notes are in the Oracle support knowledge base for WCC with sample SOAP requests for common service calls, like GET_SEARCH_RESULTS, DOC_INFO, GET_FILE, etc.